# Php скрипт который генерирует правило allow для ufw

Tags: php, firewall, ufw

Идея написать скрипт который добавляет в исключение allow на необходимый порт от машины клиента.  Получается имеем закрытый порт от ддос на уязвимое по. Есть ли такие проекты на гитхабе ? Искал не нашел

Comment: Опишите более развёрну то задачу, в принципе это не очень хорошая идея давать веб-скрипту права на изменения серверных файлов. Плюс всё можно обырать на php не прибегая к редактированию каких либо файлов.

Comment: Смотрите есть маленький проект на нем апач плюс nginx например их еще можно обезопасить или перенести на другой сервер, + есть СПО которое слабо защищено от умельцев делать плохие вещи, хотелось бы к этому сервису пускать только провереных людей например через капчу, или привязку к телефону,  на сервере есть ufw (ubuntu firewall) человек заходит на сайт жмет кнопку и скрипт php / python добавляет его ip в исключения и сервис для него доступен (открывает порт для этого ip).  В итоге сложность ддоса кокнретного сервиса уязвимого возрастает в десятки раз